# Different output when I include more columns to the select statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate, min

Why do I not get the same results when running the two queries? If I run the second one I get the course with the smallest amount of credits and when I run the first one I get the courses ordered by courseid

```
select min(credits), title, courseid 
from course 
group by title, courseid

select min(credits)
from course
```

Comment: you should take a look at the meaning and the behavior of the GROUP BY operator ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aggregation query is any query that has a `group by` or an aggregation function in the `select`.

An aggregation query returns one row per group, where a "group" is defined as the unique combination of values of the keys in the `group by` clause.  If there is no `group by` clause, then *all* rows are taken to be a single group and one row is returned.

So, your first query returns one row for each combination of `title` and `courseid` in the `course` table.  That row contains the minimum value of `credits` for that combination.  If the `course` table has only one row per `courseid`, then the results are very similar to the contents of the table.

The second query returns one row overall, with the minimum number of credits of *all* rows.

If you want to get one *row* from with the minimum number of credits, then you don't want an aggregation query.  Instead, you can use:

```
select c.*
from course c
order by c.credits
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a group by, you are using a sort of "filter", in the first query you group by title, then all the same titles are grouped by courseid, in the second you only select the minimum value of credits without filtering.

Take a look at a group by doc maybe with some graphical examples like this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-group-by/